Is it possible to create a fully-featured Kotlin multi-platform web browser using GeckoView for Android, Windows and macOS?
Currently, If I need to create a fully-featured web browser for all three major platforms, I have to:

iOS and iPadOS: Program in Swift and use WKWebView (WebKit) for the browser engine which lacks support for extensions.
macOS: Program in Swift and use the latest version of Chromium which has support for extensions but I can't get it published to the App Store because only the in-house WKWebView is officially allowed by Apple.
Windows: Program using WinUI 3.0 and the latest version of Chromium.
Android: Program in Kotlin and use GeckoView which also has support for extensions (albeit not as many as Chromium)

This means I have to maintain 4 different code bases with all 4 projects corresponding to web browsers using different browser engines and/or different implementations.
My idea is to create two code bases, one in Kotlin multi-platform using GeckoView for Android, Windows and macOS, and one in Swift using WKWebView for iOS and iPadOS. I'm currently working on the latter.
